# How does read error in swap partition affect a running process?

Tags: linux, memory, segmentation-fault, swap

Imagine:

- you have swap partition on a failing disk;
- a process is idle and part of its memory gets swapped into this partition;
- after some time it wakes up and kernel tries to load swapped pages back into the memory;
- kernel detects unrecoverable read error.

**I believe kernel should crash the process in this scenario.**

I haven't simulated it yet. I just want to know some answers (possibly with instructions how to simulate it in Linux) and share my subsequent findings as well.

Maybe this scenario can explain few crashes on some legacy systems with failing storage hardware.

**UPDATE**

Simulating errors on specific `swap` volume can easily be done using `dmsetup` with `error` mapping target:

- https://serverfault.com/a/498931
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1871029/441652

The only thing I didn't look in depth is how to control loading, swapping and re-loading virtual memory of specific process into specific `error`-mapped part of `swap` volume. Basically, I need to avoid any other processes using this erroneous `swap` except the process under simulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Poison" patch should handle your case: https://lwn.net/Articles/348886/

> Dirty pages in the swap cache are handled in a delayed fashion. The
>   dirty flag is cleared for the page and the page swap cache entry is
>   maintained. On a later page fault the associated application will be
>   killed.

Comment: qarma, thanks for the suggestion.
I looked into the article [HWPOISON patch](https://lwn.net/Articles/348886/). It deals with errors in physical memory rather than virtual memory swapping on disk. The topic is very related, but simulating errors as if they happened in physical memory does not test mechanisms of handling errors in virtual memory swapped to disk.