# Simulating bad sectors in Linux

Tags: linux

How do I simulate a bad sectors block device on Linux to test some tools?

I followed the steps in [Simulate a faulty block device with read errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870696/simulate-a-faulty-block-device-with-read-errors/1871029#1871029), but it is throwing "device-mapper: reload ioctl on bad_disk failed: Invalid argument" error.

Is there any other ways to create a bad sector block device?

Comment: Does it work fine if you simplify the description? For example remove the error block and leave only one linear device? Does it work with putting 2 devices with no error? How about error itself?

Comment: "bad sector" is ambiguous: Unreadable or unwritable? Until recently I believed that re-writing to an unreadable sector ("pending") would rellocate it; however I have a harddisk that has thousands of read errors (SMART selftests also fail), but not a single redirected sector, even after overwriting. On that disk write operations also fail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is way beyond my knowledge-base, but you may find [this discussion](http://forum.hddguru.com/viewtopic.php?t=17234&start=) useful.  They are talking about using `hdparm` and the `--make-bad-sector` option.  Buyer beware....

Another interesting discussion is [this one](http://forum.hddguru.com/viewtopic.php?t=22308&start=), which talks about the difference between actually having a bad sector and manually creating one -- depending on what tools you are testing, these two may be registered and/or treated differently?

In any case, the most relevant things I found online were from the forums at `hddguru`, so chances are the folks over there might have some good input for you :)

Hope that helps with something...