# Is it possible that application can lose I/O connection to a file?

Tags: c++, c

I have a C application. Which creates a connection to file at startup and it continuously runs for many days.

I am only connecting one time . and not reconnecting it in code. 
Only checking if

```
if(NULL == file)
```

Is there can be case that my application lose I/O connection of that file handler ?

if yes. Is there a way , How can I create test case for it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it's possible. For example if the file is on another machine or on a removable storage. Then you can physically disconnect/unplug the device and the subsequent operations on the handle will fail.

As others mentioned in the comments, you can simulate it in a test case by creating a RAM disk and either unmounting it or killing the driver. Alternatively, if all you care is about unidirectional I/O, maybe you could test your code with a pipe, and then close the other end of the pipe.

Comment: There are simpler ways to simulate this by intercepting IO calls, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361518/how-can-i-simulate-a-failed-disk-during-testing

Comment: @ybungalobill If file is same machine , and on system drive. I think in that condition connection will not lost right ?
or it can still happen while i/o cycle going above hd limit (I had read that thing somewhere but not sure )

Comment: You can have a crashed fuse driver, locally. (transport endpoint not connected error)

Comment: @Vivek: in a controlled environment, assuming no hardware failures, yes, you can assume it is never lost. In general, no. There are plenty of ways to make it happen, an it *does* happen.

Comment: @sehe  can you please provide more details ?

Comment: Yep. On linux, use fuse [to mount an fs, even local (e.g. `rofs`)](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=FileSystems#rofs); then kill/crash the fuse program (_driver_) and access the mountpoint: 'endpoint not connected'

Answer (score 8):

You can loose the connection with the file, but it won't set your file variable to NULL, the symptom will be an IO error.  Reading or writing will fail. (For C++ streams, the badbit will be set instead of the failbit which is set for format error;)