# Faking an IO Error on Linux

Tags: python, c, linux, unit-testing

I have a Python and C application on Linux that's supposed to properly handle IO errors whilst reading files from disk. The bulk of the application is written in Python, with a C extension that does the IO. It's within this extension that the IO errors are detected.

There are two cases that the errors appear to occur for me.

1. A file is missing.
2. A file appears larger on disk (using `stat`) than can be read using `fread`.

I can test and handle case number 1 rather easily. However, I'd also like to write a unit test for case 2. However, I have no idea how to trigger a "fake" IO error for the test. Is this even possible? Is there a better approach to testing this kind of error?

Comment: Side note: Simulating a file disappearing after successfully opening (e. g. it was on a memory stick now removed) might make another interesting case.

Comment: Case 2 isn't going to give you an IO error, it's just going to return fewer bytes than you expected. [`fread`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/fread.html) will return the number of elements read (and the same is true with most other functions, both in C/POSIX and in Python). And if you call `ferror()` and `feof()` to check why you got fewer results than expected, you'll get zero and nonzero, respectively. So, are you trying to test an actual I/O error, or your case 2?

Comment: @abarnert I'm referring to the errno value, which is (EIO == 5) in that case. Is this not technically an IO error?

Comment: @chux That crossed my mind, although I'm not yet sure how I'll test that either. This probably means I have to refactor my code. :-/

Comment: The errno value from what? Are you calling `fread`, then `ferror` is telling you there's an error, and then `errno` is set to EIO? If so, that doesn't mean the file is shorter than expected, this means something else (like a physical read error) has happened. If the file is just shorter than expected, that's not an error, and `ferror` must tell you so. (And if there happens to be some old error lying around in `errno`, it's irrelevant.) Unless there's a serious bug in linux or glibc, which I doubt.

Comment: The Internets are giving me conflicting information about whether `fread` sets errno. Some sources say it does, other say it's not required but may depend on the implementation. I guess I *should* be using ferror anyway.

Comment: But yes, the underlying problem is definitely a physical read error (bad sector on disk, I suppose.)

Comment: What exactly is your Python & C application doing? If it is so critical (e.g. life-critical embedded software) are you sure that Python is the best choice???

Comment: No, it's definitely not doing anything critical. The reason it has to handle this kind of IO error is because it reads a huge amount of data. (At this kind of scale, in fact, it's just an inevitability that some files can't be read, due to disk issues.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand the matter, classics of TDD warn us against writing mocks/stubs for 3rd-party interfaces (including standard library), see e.g. [here](http://www.mockobjects.com/2007/04/test-smell-everything-is-mocked.html). The major issue is that there is usually a gap between the application code and generic-purpose 3rd-party library which is hard to tie with mock-objects. Also, that prevents you from using tests to derive the design issues.

(Even though in your case the C library is not exactly 3rd party, unit-testing means that you test the entities in isolation).

The idea is that instead you write an adaptor class that encapsulates all the low-level logic and exposes an interface close to what your application needs (and, for example, raises more meaningful exceptions, like `FileIsTooBig`). Then you write mock-objects in terms of your domain. As for testing the adaptor itself, it's tested with few simple system tests.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm accepting this answer because it helps me understand how I should approach the problem from a software architecture standpoint.

Answer (score 6):

[errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) is set to `EIO` only for

> ```
>    EIO    Input/output error (POSIX.1)
> ```

also, according to [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) for:

> ```
>    EIO    I/O error.  This will happen for example when the process is
>           in a background process group, tries to read from its
>           controlling terminal, and either it is ignoring or blocking
>           SIGTTIN or its process group is orphaned.  It may also occur
>           when there is a low-level I/O error while reading from a 
>           disk or tape.
> ```

and according to [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) for:

> ```
>    EIO    A low-level I/O error occurred while modifying the inode.
> ```

So simulating that particular error code could be difficult; notice that there are other syscalls for I/O, notably [writev(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/writev.2.html) and (indirectly) [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), but `read(2)` and `write(2)` are the most common ones.

Notice also that [file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) and the [Linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) (e.g. its [VFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_file_system) layer) are [caching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_%28computing%29) data. You could get `EIO` much later or never. See [sync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html) and [fsync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fsync.2.html)

However, generally, most software does not handle `EIO` specially w.r.t. other error codes; you probably are testing enough by getting another error code, like e.g.

> ```
>   EDQUOT The user's quota of disk blocks on the filesystem containing
>           the file referred to by fd has been exhausted.
> ```

So you'll probably test enough by limiting [disk quotas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_quota) (see [quotactl(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/quotactl.2.html), [setquota(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/setquota.8.html) etc...) and file space (see [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) with `RLIMIT_FSIZE`, [prlimit(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/prlimit.1.html), `ulimit` builtin of [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) etc...)

If you really want to fake specifically `EIO`  you could physically damage a device (or perhaps just unplug an USB disk at the wrong moment) or write your own [Filesystem in User Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) (FUSE) simulating it. I don't think it is worth the effort (because when something gets `EIO`  the entire computer becomes very quickly unusable, and the user will notice that anyway.... and because most software handle all error codes likewise -except for `EINTR`)

In the C part of your code you may want to use [strerror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) (with [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) perhaps) and/or [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html). I am not sure it is worth the effort to handle `EIO` very differently of most other errors.

NB: many critical domains have standards defining how errors should be handled and code should be developed and tested, e.g. [ISO26262](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_26262) in automotive or [DO-178B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DO-178B) in avionics. Follow the standards of your domain.

Answer (score 1):

Use [fusepy](https://github.com/terencehonles/fusepy).

fusepy is a python layer on top of FUSE, which allows file systems to be implemented in the Linux user space. fusepy is a Python module that provides a simple interface to FUSE and MacFUSE. It's just one file and is implemented using ctypes. With fusepy, you can modify the behavior of the `write` function implementation and throw an `EIO` if you want to. I'd use the `memory.py` example as a base.

Answer (score 1):

[libfiu](https://blitiri.com.ar/p/libfiu/) (as mentioned in the ["How can I simulate a failed disk during testing?" answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1363702/2732969)) is a structured approach to using interposing to perform fault injection of POSIX calls and would be ideal for use in test suites.

A more general list of techniques (such as using a FUSE filesystem) are mentioned in the [list of Linux disk fault injection mechanisms](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144200/61610) answer to the ["Special File that causes I/O error" question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77492/special-file-that-causes-i-o-error/144200#144200).